# installing dependencies always abort

Tags: package-management, dependencies

When I install any dependency and when it asks yes/no and I say yes it aborts:

```
hassan@hassan-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/Python-2.7.11$ sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcc-4.9-base gcc-4.9-base:i386 libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6:i386 libc6-dbg
  libc6-dev libgcc1 libgcc1:i386 libpthread-stubs0-dev:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-doc libxau-dev:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcb1-dev:i386
  libxdmcp-dev:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386 libxcb-doc:i386
Recommended packages:
  libx11-doc:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed
  gcc-4.9-base:i386 libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libpthread-stubs0-dev:i386
  libx11-6:i386 libx11-dev:i386 libx11-doc libxau-dev:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb1:i386 libxcb1-dev:i386 libxdmcp-dev:i386 libxdmcp6:i386
  x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools
  xtrans-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gcc-4.9-base libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libgcc1
6 to upgrade, 18 to newly install, 0 to remove and 293 not to upgrade.
Need to get 18.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 28.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Abort.
```

Comment: Just a guess, but do you have 32bit support, for the i386 packages? Run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and try again.

Comment: thanks for the advice but it still aborts when i say yes

Answer (score 1):

You do something wrong when you are asked if you want to continue. Run the command this way:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libx11-dev:i386
```

The system will not ask for a confirmation.